# use Broadcast receiver to receive ViewPager.getCurrentItem() changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-viewpager

The title says it , I want to use a Broadcast Receiver to watch my ViewPager.getCurrentItem() changes  , so that when the user turns from first page to second page , the value of `ViewPager.getCurrentItem` changes from 0 to 1 ... When it changes I want to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` so i can setup new menuItems for the new page ... Can anybody help me in that ?

EDIT :

My purpose is now done by an answer i got in the comments , however , I still need an answer for utilizing Broadcast Receiver for the operation , for later on use ...

Comment: you can use onPageChangeListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Comment: U ARE THE MAN !  thx dude ...

Comment: you can create custom broadcast and broadcast receiver @Seaskyways this article may of help http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver

Comment: please up vote comment if it helps

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan thx , just did vote , didn't realize before i could do that :p plz you vote up my question too if you find it useful . An plus you just gave an answer , write it down in the answers section !

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Shared Preferences to do this......Its less complex.....These tutorials should help....

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12260/android-sharedpreferences-example/

http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html

Comment: I already use SharedPreferences for preserving some values when I close my app , but in my case they will not anywhere help me . If you have anyway they can , tell me ...

Answer (score 0):

> When it changes I want to invalidateOptionsMenu() so i can setup new menuItems for the new page

That needs to be called by an `Activity`. `BroadcastReceiver` does not have `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

> I still need an answer for utilizing Broadcast Receiver for the operation , for later on use ...

You have provided no evidence whatsoever that a `BroadcastReceiver` would be useful to you.

That being said, your `OnPageChangedListener`, if it is implemented as a regular inner class of your `Activity`, is welcome to call `sendBroadcast()` to send a broadcast about the current-page change.

Comment: I need the BroadcastReceiver for example if a File's readout changes,  so instead of checking if it changed every period of time,  the receiver will just detect the change and do whatsoever it has to do...  And btw i can run ′invalidateOptionsMenu' through a runnable and handler...

Comment: @Seaskyways: "if a File's readout changes" has nothing to do with a `ViewPager`. "And btw i can run ′invalidateOptionsMenu' through a runnable and handler" -- only if the `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of an `Activity`, which means it is really the `Activity` that you are calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on.

Comment: "if a File's readout changes" , no body **here** said that am talking about a viewPager , I am talking about a file ...

and "only if the BroadcastReceiver is an inner class of an Activity" is exactly what i mean to do , I don't make another class file for my BroadcastReceiver ...

Comment: @Seaskyways: "no body here said that am talking about a viewPager" -- your original question is about using a `BroadcastReceiver` with a `ViewPager`. Note that there are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering assistance in a variety of languages. I have several listed at http://www.andglobe.com. Perhaps you will have better luck using a site that operates in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: Thank you anyway , I've got what I needed , and ur right , this question is about viewPager , because of that I asked another about the File and got my answer ...